# Bring selected arc hovered over by user to front and dim the display of all other arcs

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, mouseevent

I have created a visualization using D3.js which connects arcs across a map. The data is read from a csv file and the arcs are connected using some filters. Depending on the input provided by the user, in some cases there is a clutter of arcs that gets plotted between different points on the map(see picture below). At present I have coded it such that when the user hovers over the arc, that particular arc will get highlighted.

[image]

I have two question on this scenario :-

1) How to bring the arc that has been hovered over by the user to the front of the display screen in case of a clutter of arcs

2) Is it possible to dim the background color of all other arcs and only highlight the arc in question which has been selected by the user. In other, words, I wish to dim the intensity of display for all other arcs except for the arc selected by the user

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's very hard to provide an answer without seeing any code, but here it is:

First, set a class to your arcs (like `.foo`). Then, define the mouseover and mouseout events:

```
var myArcs = d3.selectAll(".foo");

myArcs.on("mouseover", function(d){
    myArcs.attr("opacity", 0.2);//tweak this value
    d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1);
    d3.select(this).raise();
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    myArcs.attr("opacity", 1);
});
```

Notice that `raise()` is only available in D3 v4.x. Besides that, `raise()` will not work (for what you want) if those paths are buried inside separate groups.

Here is a demo:

```js
var w = 500, h = 300;
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", w)
 .attr("height", h);
 
var data = d3.range(100);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var lines = svg.selectAll(".lines")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("line")
 .attr("stroke-width", 4)
 .attr("stroke", (d,i)=> color(i))
 .attr("x1", ()=>Math.random()*w)
 .attr("x2", ()=>Math.random()*w)
 .attr("y1", ()=>Math.random()*h)
 .attr("y2", ()=>Math.random()*h);
 
lines.on("mouseover", function(d){
    lines.attr("opacity", 0.2);
    d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1);
    d3.select(this).raise();
}).on("mouseout", function(){
    lines.attr("opacity", 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```